# How to use php version according to magento version?

Tags: php-7, magento1.9.3, magento1.9.2.4, magento-upgrade, php-5.6

I have

> php 5.6 & php 7.0.3

on the server. I am upgrading the website `magento 1.9.2.4 to magento 1.9.3.9` which is showing me an error of php version.

> CONNECT ERROR: Package community/Interface_Adminhtml_Default 1.9.3.9:
>   requires PHP version >= 5.2.0 and <= 6.0.0 current is: 7.0.30

**So how can I choose php 5.6 for magento 1.9.3.9?**

Or any other way to upgrading magento 1.9.3.9

Comment: Is this solution helped?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set your version to php 5.6

Add this line in .htaccess of Magento if you use apache2

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php56 .php
```